# Swiper JS - Loop parameter not working anymore

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I used to have a slider in loop on a site I've been working on. I'm currently updating this website and the loop doesn't work anymore.

I use Swiper JS in its latest version for now (9.3.2), and it seems that the **loop parameter** doesn't work anymore.

It works perfectly fine when I use it in its 9.1.1 version on another project.

Did something change that I should know? Is it a bug? Should I wait for the next version to fix it or can I do something in the meantime?

This is the Javascript I have right now:

```
const mySwiper = new Swiper('#mySlider', {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 20,
  loop: true,
  allowTouchMove: false,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 1500,
  },
  navigation: {
    prevEl: '.my-slider-prev',
    nextEl: '.my-slider-next',
  },
  breakpoints: {
    500: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
    },
    850: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
    },
  },
  modules: [Autoplay, Navigation]
});
```